# Instant selection with dynamic columns in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have the problem with making Instant Selection when columns is dynamic and presented as List of Maps:

```
private List<Map<String,DataWindowField>> columns;
```

How it works now:
I have a class that called from ViewedScoped bean:

```
public class DataWindow extends Utility
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private TransactionObject transObject;
public Main main; 
private String sqlStatement; 

private List<Map<String,DataWindowField>> columns;
private List<DataWindowHeader> headers;
    public List<Map<String,DataWindowField>> getColumns() {
    return columns;
}
public void setColumns(List<Map<String,DataWindowField>> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}

public List<DataWindowHeader> getHeaders() {
    return headers;
}

public List<DataWindowHeader> getVisibleHeaders() {
    List<DataWindowHeader> visibleHeaders=new ArrayList<DataWindowHeader>();

    for(DataWindowHeader header:headers)
    {
        if(header.isVisible()==true)
        {
            visibleHeaders.add(header);
        }
    }
    return visibleHeaders;

}
public void setHeaders(List<DataWindowHeader> headers) {
    this.headers = headers;
}
}
```

Xhtml file for this class is looks like here:

```
<p:dataTable id="dw_favorites_detail" var="column" value="#{dw.columns}" scrollable="false">                      
        <p:columns var="column_header" value="#{dw.getVisibleHeaders()}">
            #{column[column_header.dbAlias].value}  
        </p:columns>  

    </p:dataTable>
```

I need such construction because visibility of the entire column can be changed during execution.

And my question is How to create DataModel for such rows to make Instant selection?

My current model is not finished because I don't know how to correspond selected row with Map:

```
public class DataWindowRowModel extends ListDataModel<Map<String,DataWindowColumn>> implements SelectableDataModel<Map<String,DataWindowColumn>> {


@Override
public Map<String,DataWindowColumn> getRowData(String arg0) {
    List<Map<String,DataWindowColumn>> columns=(List<Map<String,DataWindowColumn>>) getWrappedData();
    for(Map<String,DataWindowColumn> column:columns)
    {

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(Map<String,DataWindowColumn> rowdata) {

     return rowdata;  

}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected this in next way and it select columns well:

```
public class DataWindowRowModel extends ListDataModel<Map<String,DataWindowField>> implements SelectableDataModel<Map<String,DataWindowField>> {

 public DataWindowRowModel() {  
    }  

public DataWindowRowModel(List<Map<String,DataWindowField>> columns)
{

    super(columns); 
}
@Override
public Map<String,DataWindowField> getRowData(String rowKey) {
    Map<String,DataWindowField> currentRowMap=new HashMap<String,DataWindowField>();
    List<Map<String,DataWindowField>> row=(List<Map<String,DataWindowField>>) getWrappedData();
    for(Map<String,DataWindowField> column:row)
    {
        for(DataWindowField value:column.values())
        {
            if(value.getValue().equals(rowKey));
            return column;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(Map<String,DataWindowField> rowdata) {
    for(DataWindowField value:rowdata.values())
    {
        return value.getValue();

    }

    return null;
}
```

}

And xhtml file:

```
<p:dataTable id="dw_favorites_detail" var="column" value="#{dw.rowModel}" selection="#{dw.row}" scrollable="false" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{dw.onRowSelect}"/>                      
        <p:columns var="column_header" value="#{dw.getVisibleHeaders()}" width="20%">
            #{column[column_header.dbAlias].value}  
        </p:columns>  

    </p:dataTable>
```